# Discord Doesn't Show Server Members with Role

Tags: node.js, discord.js

The following code is returning the wrong information in the field

`.addField('Usuarios con el Rol', roleMembers.length > 0 ? roleMembers.join(', ') : 'No hay usuarios con este rol', false)`

should return a list of all users who have the mentioned role. What you're doing is returning the name of the owner of the role.

```
else if (command === 'rol_info') {
    // Verificar que se proporcione el argumento necesario
    if (args.length !== 1) {
        return message.reply('Uso correcto: -s rol_info <nombre_del_rol>');
    }

    const roleName = args[0]; // Nombre del rol

    // Verificar si el rol existe en la base de datos
    dbConnection.query('SELECT * FROM roles WHERE nombre_del_rol = ?', [roleName], async (err, rows) => {
        if (err) throw err;

        if (rows.length === 0) {
            return message.reply(`No se encontró ningún rol con el nombre "${roleName}".`);
        }

        const roleData = rows[0];
        const ownerId = roleData.owner_del_rol.replace(/<@!?(.*)>/, '$1'); // ID del propietario del rol
        const owner = message.guild.members.cache.get(ownerId); // Obtener el miembro que corresponde al ID
        const roleMembers = message.guild.roles.cache.find(role => role.name === roleName).members.map(member => member.user.tag); // Obtener los miembros con el rol
        const embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
            .setColor(roleData.color)
            .setTitle(`Información del Rol "${roleName}"`)
            .addField('Owner del Rol', owner ? owner.user.tag : 'No disponible', true)
            .addField('Límite de Usuarios', roleData.limite_de_usuarios.toString(), true)
            .addField('Usuarios con el Rol', roleMembers.length > 0 ? roleMembers.join(', ') : 'No hay usuarios con este rol', false)
            .addField('Tipo de Rol', roleData.tipo, true);

        message.channel.send({ embeds: [embed] });
    });
  }
```

Comment: What is it returning instead?